# Limit of $\frac{2^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

The way I see it is that denominator is super-exponential and the numerator is only exponential, so this must be $0$ but wolfram is saying it is infinite.

How do I evaluate this limit?

Comment: @Mourad are you sure about that? it is not very different from $n^{1/n}$. Maybe I am getting rusty at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You can rewrite it as follows:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp{(n \ln{2}-\sqrt{n} \ln{n})}$$

Can you take it from here?

Edit: Now you only need to notice, that $n \ln{2}$ grows faster than $\sqrt{n} \ln{n}$.

Comment: @Andronicus, that is not true.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: Saying you need to notice that $n\ln(2)$ grows faster than .. is like basically saying $2^n$ grows faster than $n^{\sqrt{n}}$. Don't see a point in that

Comment: @Paul how I understand that is that root is for checking convergence of a sequence, not a limit. No sum is here

Comment: That's correct, but you said that the root test is for sequences.

Comment: @Mourad you can reduce the problem to the following: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \ln{2}}{\sqrt{n} \ln{n}}$

Comment: @AshwiniPatil sorry for the confusion. You can use the root test if you're checking if the sum is convergent!

Comment: @Paul ok, you're right, I expressed myself wrong, thank you:)

Comment: Still, I don't understand the downvote. Can anyone explain? (No revenge)

Comment: @Andronicus I am not checking the sum. So root test is basically useless and you were correct. actually I got mixed up. I have been away for too long.

Answer (score 3):

You need  some (easy) asymptotic analysis to obtain the limit.

As already noted
$$\frac{2^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}=\mathrm e^{n\ln 2-\sqrt{n}\ln n}=\mathrm e^{n\ln 2\bigl(1-\tfrac{\ln n}{\sqrt n\ln 2}\bigr)}.$$
Now it is standard that 
$$\ln n=o(\sqrt n)\enspace\text{ –  in other words },\; \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}=0.$$
Therefore, the second factor in the exponent tends to $1$, and consequently the exponent  itself tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By substituting $n=2^{t}$, we obtain $${2^n\over n^{\sqrt n}}={2^{2^t}\over 2^{t\cdot 2^{t\over 2}}}=2^{2^t-t\cdot 2^{t\over 2}}$$which tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-(A way to see it) The derivative of $f(x)=\dfrac{2^x}{x^{\sqrt{x}}}$ is equal to $\dfrac{2^{x-1}}{x^{\sqrt x-0.5}}(\sqrt x\ln4-2-\ln x)$ and it has only one zero at $x_0\approx 9.319913$. It is not difficult to see that $f$ has a minimum at $x_0$ then that  for $x\gt x_0$   the function is strictly increasing. You can deduce this way that your limit is not $0$ and it is according with Wolfram says.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose, $a^2<n<(a+1)^2$
It means $2^{\sqrt n}>2^a>(a+1)^2>n$ for $ n>5$, 
So now we have $\frac{2^{\sqrt n}}{n}>1$ hence the limit is infinity. 
again if,  $n=a^2$ then we have $ 2^a>a^2$ again the fraction is larger than $1$ hence $c_n^{\sqrt n}$ tends to $\infty$, 
With $c_n>1$. also $c_{n+1}>c_n$,  where $c_n=\frac {2^{\sqrt n}}{n}$.

Note :  the function $\frac {2^{\sqrt n}}{n}$ is increasing.